# Why is Internet Explorer changing the background colour on my image from white to grey?

Tags: image, internet-explorer, background, jpeg

I am using a logo with a white background and in the format of a .jpg. For some reason Internet Explorer is changing the white background to grey. I'm not sure why, I've searched the internet but cannot find anyone with the same problem.

Comment: It only happens with IE ? Is it possible to have a test page ? Try to use a Color Picker to figure out what is the code of your not-so-white white (I think your problem is here because even for IE, white is white).

Comment: You can actually see it here: http://dominicsutherland.com/velenski with the password: velenski2013 .